# Error in copying SSH key in clipboard by cmd

Tags: windows, git, ssh, gitlab-ci, cat

After generating ssh key. I tried to copy the public key into the clipboard by following the instruction so that I can add into my account.

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub | clip
```

reference: [https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ssh/index.html#add-an-ssh-key-to-your-gitlab-account]

but getting this error.
[https://ibb.co/vdC3CCB]

Generated link for image online as due to less reputation I am not allowed to add image.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of issues here. Firstly, you're clearly using a linux guide on a windows machine. Windows uses backslashes for file paths, not forward slashes. Secondly, `cat ~/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub | clip` is a linux command, you want to use `type C:\Path\to\file.pub | clip` to achieve the same thing. Windows also doesn't support `~` for referencing the user's home directory.

You may have issues other than this, since you're not following a windows specific guide.